# Deployed Nextjs site to Firebase hosting but link prefetching and images receive 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: firebase-hosting, next.js13

I deployed Nextjs 13 website to Firebase hosting, and both links prefetching and images do not work.  They receive 503 Service Unavailable. I must reload the page several times for images to start showing up, but they are so slow.

Everything works when I run npm run build and npm run start. What is it that I am missing?

I am using:
firebase tools:  12.5.4

next: ^13.4.19
firebase": ^10.4.0
firebase-admin: ^11.10.1

Answer (score 0):

I finally solve the problem by increasing the amount of memory used by the ssr function deployed with NextJs.  It seems that the whole website is in this function.  Here is how you add more memory to this function:
in firebase.json add this:

```
  "hosting": {
    "source": "directory that has your Next js",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "us-west1",
      "minInstances": 0,  <------- you can configure these too
      "maxInstances": 100, <------ and this one
      "memory": "1GiB" <------- this line will increase the memory
    }
  },
```

One more thing, make sure you have the latest and greatest version of Firebase CLI.  This is extremely important especially that everything is in beta these days as far as Next js 13 goes.